# Apply a dashed border to a masked Image in SwiftUI

Tags: border, swiftui, mask

I have an Image that is masked by an image asset. I'd like to apply a dashed border to the Image so that the dashed border shape follows the mask whatever it is.

```
Image(uiImage: self.helper.loadedImage!)
.resizable()
.scaledToFill()
.foregroundColor(Color.clear)
.background(Color.clear)
.frame(width: 200, height: 200, alignment: .center)
.clipped()
.mask(Image(uiImage: self.helper.loadedMaskImage!)
.resizable()
.frame(width: 200, height: 200, alignment: .center))
```

This image is rendered correctly. If loadedMaskImage is a circle for example, i see the original image in a circle shape. Now i'd like to show a circle dashed border on this image. But I don't want to use any specific shape, because the loadedMaskImage can be anything at runtime.
Is this possible without diving back into UIKit UIView?

EDIT:
This is how i can mask the view. In this case i'm using a circle image as a mask and the result is correct. Now on top of this i'd like to have a dashed border that has the same shape of that circle.

[image]

Comment: Not sure I understood correctly what you're going to achieve (taking into account provided code). Could you demo somehow, mock ups or screenshot or something?

Comment: @asperi Added a photo and some details.

Answer (score 1):

The dashed border can be achieved by using a dashed stroke of color **over the image using a ZStack**

```
 Circle()
    .stroke(Color.blue, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth:5 , lineCap: .round, dash:[10, 5]))
    .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
```

*The `dash` argument is an array where here it means for every 10 length of showing the border there should be 5 length of no border which appears as dashed border,*

I set the width and height of the frame exactly equal to your image's width and height so that it looks as though the circle is just bordering your image

You can set the first property to anything like `Color.black.opacity(0.4)` or even a `LinearGradient` if you wish so...

Comment: Thanks for your answer but as I stated I cannot use a fixed shape like Circle. The masks I’m using are images of any shape, so I need a general working solution. My circle image is just an example. Again thanks though.